# Monitoring a file and wanting to send an email with the `mail` command

Tags: bash, shell, email, mailx

I am going to monitor a file with a [ -s filename ] option and when that file gets data, to email me with appropriate information. I've searched the site and came up with a few options, but didn't click for me.

I'm trying to do the following to simply test "mail" I've also tried `mailx`. The user did not receive the email and the output provided is exactly the same for `mail` and `mailx`.

Ultimately, I'm going to edit the original bash script with the mail or mailx command, assuming I can get it to work.

This is what I'm doing and output 
command line returns when I hit, enter.

Thank you for any input for this, I totally appreciate it.

---

```
[user@somehost ~]$ echo "TEST" | mail -s subject user@mail.com

[user@somehost ~]$ send-mail: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
send-mail: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
```

Comment: Updated with recommendations; thank you!

Comment: Tnks for that. The answer below looks like a great place to start. Does it work for you? If not, then  you need to dig down on why sendmail isn't working. Could be a lot of reasons, and if that is the case, better to post at http://unix.stackexchange.com .Good luck.

Comment: Awesome! I agree, its a great starting point; thank you. 

I am on a work network at the moment, so I'm not sure how or if I can, configure SMTP_SERVER.

Comment: This helped get me to the point where I understand what I need to gather. Thank you again, very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `inotifywait` for the event you're after (perhaps `CLOSE_WRITE`?).

You'll need to configure your mailer with an SMTP server, and possibly (hopefully) some credentials.

I usually use the `mailx` from the `heirloom-mailx` package, with the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/false

function send_email {
  # args are: subject [to] [from_name] [from_address]
  #   subject is required
  #   to and from_* are optional, defaults below

  # stdin takes the message body... don't forget

  # this function uses mailx from heirloom-mailx

  local SMTP_SRVR="${YOUR_SERVER}"
  local SMTP_USER="${YOUR_USERNAME}"
  local SMTP_PASS="${YOUR_PASSWORD}"

  local DEFAULT_TO="${YOUR_RECIPIENT}"
  local DEFAULT_FROM_NAME="${YOUR_SENDER_NAME}"
  local DEFAULT_FROM_ADDR="${YOUR_SENDER_EMAIL}"

  if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "${FUNCNAME}(): missing subject (arg 1)..." >&2
    return 1
  fi
  local SUBJECT="$1"
  shift

  if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    local TO="${DEFAULT_TO}"
  else
    local TO="$1"
    shift
  fi

  if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    local FROM="${DEFAULT_FROM_NAME}"
  else
    local FROM="$1"
    shift
  fi

  if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    FROM="${FROM} <${DEFAULT_FROM_ADDR}>"
  else
    FROM="${FROM} <$1>"
    shift
  fi

  mailx -s"${SUBJECT}" -r"${FROM}" -Ssmtp="${SMTP_SRVR}" -Ssmtp-auth-user="${SMTP_USER}" -Ssmtp-auth-password="${SMTP_PASS}" "${TO}"
  return $?
}
```

You can then use the above (e.g: `my_send_email.inc`) from another script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source my_send_email.inc

echo "Testing" | send_email "${MY_EMAIL}"
```